# toggle stays active when status is inactive

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I'm using angular and jQuery. I have a toggle button set with a status so when the page loads the toggle button stays active even when the status has been changed and saved to inactive. Is there any way to keep the toggle on active state when active and inactive state when inactive?

the js:

```
$scope.isActive = true;
$scope.isStatusActive = function() {
    $scope.isActive = !$scope.isActive;
    if ($scope.isActive) {
        $scope.site.status = 'ACTIVE';
    } else {
        console.log('active');
        $scope.site.status = 'INACTIVE';
    }
}
```

the html:

```
<div class="ui toggle checkbox left floated" style="margin-top: 4px !important;left: 10px !important;">
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model='isActive' ng-change=isStatusActive()>
    <label>{{site.status}}</label>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you post relevant controller code?

Comment: want the toggle to recognize when status is active or in active and match p accordingly, so when its inactive i want the toggle to show inactive and so on for the rest of them on the page cause theres some thats active and inactive so i want to get them to match up accordingly its a semantic toggle.

Comment: $scope.isStatusActive=function(){
        $scope.isActive=!$scope.isActive;
            if($scope.isActive){
                $scope.site.status='ACTIVE';           
            }
            else{
                console.log('active')
                $scope.site.status='INACTIVE';
                  
   
            }
        }

Comment: how would i get it to recognise the active/inactive state when the window loads because currently its on constantly, if i change $scope.isActive to false it shows inactive toggle but the ones that are active also show inactive, maybe thats more clear?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$scope.isActive = !$scope.isActive;
```

It will toggle the boolean value.